# Name the graph class: Disjoint union of a clique and an independent set

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-classes

Let $G$ be a graph which is the disjoint union of a clique and an independent set, i.e.
$$G = K_{n_1} + \overline{K_{n_2}} = K_{n_1} + I_{n_2} .$$

The graph class of all such graphs is characterized by the forbidden induced subgraphs set $\mathcal{H} = \{2K_2, P_3\}$ and is thus the intersection of a cluster graph and a split (or threshold) graph.

Does this (very simple) graph class have a name?  I was unable to find the graph class on [ISGCI](http://www.graphclasses.org/), and the papers I know on the topic (e.g. [Editing Simple Graphs](http://jgaa.info/getPaper?id=337) and [On the clique editing problem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-44465-8_40)) do not refer to the class by a name.

Here is a figure of such a graph:

[image: cluster-split graph]

Comment: Unfortunately "split cluster graphs" seems to be in use for a different concept (graphs in which each connected component is split).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edge-complement of graphs in your class are complete split graphs: they can be partitioned into an independent set and a clique, such that every vertex in the independent set is adjacent to every vertex in the clique (see, for example, http://www.mathcove.net/petersen/lessons/get-lesson?les=30 ). Hence you could call your graph class co-complete split graphs.

Comment: Thanks, Bart.  It doesn't exactly roll off the tongue, but I guess it'll have to do.

Comment: What about _independent split graph_?  Or would that be likely to be confused with something else?

Answer (score 7):

In a recent article, Hüffner, Komusiewicz, and Nichterlein refer to this class as **sparse split graphs**.  They also refer to the complement class, the complete split graphs, as *dense split graphs*.

Hüffner, Komusiewicz, and Nichterlein. *"Editing Graphs into Few Cliques: Complexity, Approximation, and Kernelization Schemes."*